# error during callback cplex, I can't solve it

Tags: python, cplex

I'm trying to develop an algorithm to solve a specific mixed integer problem in cplex.

When I try to run the algorithm, I get the following text:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  Here the log shows the directory of the files of my algorithm for a few lines
.
.
.
.

and finally:
  File "/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cplex/__init__.py", line 1099, in solve
    _proc.mipopt(self._env._e, self._lp)
  File "/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cplex/_internal/_procedural.py", line 629, in mipopt
    check_status(env, status)
  File "/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cplex/_internal/_procedural.py", line 303, in __call__
    raise CplexSolverError(error_string, env, status)
cplex.exceptions.errors.CplexSolverError: CPLEX Error  1006: Error during callback.
```

Do you have any idea of what could cause error in that files?

I have a few code files:

This is the file where the resolution is launched, it is called G_resoluciones:

```py
import G_Callbacks
import G_Heuristica
import gc
import D2MIPpG
import cplex
import os   

def ResolvemosBC_q_C_norm(E,I,J,K,p,R,C):

    D2_C_DrBC_C_norm = open(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), '..'))+"/G_ResultsD2_C_DrBC_Cp_norm.txt", "a") 
    tiemposD2_C_DrBC_norm = {} 
    tiemposRelD2_C_DrBC_norm = {}
    nodosD2_C_DrBC_norm = {}
    CODD2_C_DrBC_norm={}
    ValObjD2_C_DrBC_norm = {}
    ValRelD2_C_DrBC_norm = {}
    MSJD2_C_DrBC_norm = {}
    MIPGAPD2_C_DrBC_norm = {}
    OptimalityGapD2_C_DrBC_norm = {}
    CutsD2_C_DrBC_norm = {}
    IterD2_C_DrBC_norm = {}
    BestBoundD2_C_DrBC_norm = {}
    IncD2_C_DrBC_norm = {}
    LP_GORDO_C_DrBC_norm = {}

    sH,thetaH,xH,qH,fobjH={},{},{},{},{} 
    m1 = D2MIPpG.solveD2(I,J,K,p,R,C) 
    sH,thetaH,xH,qH,fobjH=G_Heuristica.HeuristicaGeneral(p,I,K,J,R,C) 
    qHH={}
    indi=[]

    for k in range(K):
        for j in range(J):
            qHH[J*k+j]=qH[k,j]

    coefi=[]   
    for i in range(I):
        coefi.append(xH[i])
    for j in range(I,I+J*K,1):
        coefi.append(qHH[j-I])
    for j in range(I+J*K,I+J*K+K,1):
        coefi.append(sH[j-I-J*K])
    for j in range(I+J*K+K,I+J*K+K+K,1):
        coefi.append(thetaH[j-I-J*K-K])

    for i in range(len(coefi)):
        indi.append(i)

    m1.MIP_starts.add(cplex.SparsePair(ind=indi, val=coefi), m1.MIP_starts.effort_level.solve_fixed,"primera")   # primeros valores


    Nodos_cb = m1.register_callback(G_Callbacks.Nodos) 
    Nodos_cb.times_called = 0
    Inc=m1.register_callback(G_Callbacks.Incumbente) 

    G_Callbacks.Cplex_callback_D2BC_C_norm.model=m1   
    G_Callbacks.Cplex_callback_D2BC_C_norm.thetaVars=m1._data[3]
    G_Callbacks.Cplex_callback_D2BC_C_norm.qVars=m1._data[1]


    e=m1.register_callback(G_Callbacks.Cplex_callback_D2BC_C_norm)
    e.iterations=0
    e.iterationsR=0
    m1.parameters.mip.cuts.mircut.set(-1)
    m1.parameters.mip.cuts.gomory.set(-1)
    m1.parameters.mip.limits.treememory.set(50000)
    m1.parameters.mip.strategy.file.set(3)
    m1.parameters.workmem.set(10000)
    m1.parameters.timelimit.set(18000)
    m1.parameters.preprocessing.presolve.set(0)
    m1.parameters.preprocessing.numpass.set(0)
    m1.parameters.threads.set(1)
    m1.parameters.mip.strategy.fpheur.set(-1)
    m1.parameters.mip.strategy.heuristicfreq.set(-1)
    m1.parameters.mip.strategy.lbheur.set(0)
    m1.parameters.mip.strategy.rinsheur.set(-1)
    # m5._alpha=alpha
    ValorObjetivoMejorado={}
    Counter={}
    m1._Counter = Counter
    m1._ValorObjetivoMejorado = ValorObjetivoMejorado

    m1._qH=qH
    m1._thetaH=thetaH
    m1._fobjH=fobjH
    m1._K = K
    m1._J = J
    m1._p = p
    m1._I = I
    m1._R = R
    m1._C = C
    m1._FirstTime=1
    start = m1.get_time()
    m1.solve() #this is where the spyder says the error is
    end = m1.get_time()
    elapsed = end - start
    solrEC_D=m1.solution
    elapsedLP=e.stopic-start

    ValObjD2_C_DrBC_norm,tiemposD2_C_DrBC_norm, nodosD2_C_DrBC_norm, MSJD2_C_DrBC_norm, CODD2_C_DrBC_norm,ValRelD2_C_DrBC_norm, tiemposRelD2_C_DrBC_norm, MIPGAPD2_C_DrBC_norm,OptimalityGapD2_C_DrBC_norm, CutsD2_C_DrBC_norm,IterD2_C_DrBC_norm,BestBoundD2_C_DrBC_norm,LP_GORDO_C_DrBC_norm=Escribe_Resultados_CUTANDBRANCH(m1,Nodos_cb,e,elapsed,elapsedLP)

    D2_C_DrBC_C_norm.write('G_B&C_q_norm')
    D2_C_DrBC_C_norm.write(' %d %d %d %d ' % (E, I, J, K))
    D2_C_DrBC_C_norm.write(' %0.4f %0.4f %d %s %d %0.4f %0.4f %0.4f' % (float(ValObjD2_C_DrBC_norm), float(tiemposD2_C_DrBC_norm), nodosD2_C_DrBC_norm, MSJD2_C_DrBC_norm,CODD2_C_DrBC_norm, float(ValRelD2_C_DrBC_norm), float(tiemposRelD2_C_DrBC_norm), float(MIPGAPD2_C_DrBC_norm)))
    D2_C_DrBC_C_norm.write(' %0.4f %d %d %0.4f' % (float(OptimalityGapD2_C_DrBC_norm), CutsD2_C_DrBC_norm,IterD2_C_DrBC_norm,float(BestBoundD2_C_DrBC_norm)))                   
    D2_C_DrBC_C_norm.write(' %0.4f ' %(LP_GORDO_C_DrBC_norm))
    D2_C_DrBC_C_norm.write(' 1')
    D2_C_DrBC_C_norm.write("\n")   



    del m1
    gc.collect()


def Escribe_Resultados_CUTANDBRANCH(modelo, callback1, callback2, elapsed, elapsedLP):

    ValObj,tiempos,nodos, MSJ,COD,ValRel,tiemposRel,MIPGAP,OptimalityGap,Cuts,Iter,BestBound,LP_GORDO = {},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{}

    solrEC_D=modelo.solution
#OPTIMAL INTEGER SOLUTION FOUND OR OPTIMAL SOLUTION WITH EPGAP OR EPAGAP TOLERANCE FOUND
    if solrEC_D.get_status()==101 or solrEC_D.get_status()==102:
        ValObj=solrEC_D.get_objective_value()
        tiempos=elapsed
        nodos=callback2.nodecnt
        MSJ=solrEC_D.status[solrEC_D.get_status()]
        COD=solrEC_D.get_status()
        ValRel=callback2.LPValueWithCuts
        tiemposRel=elapsedLP
        MIPGAP=((ValRel-ValObj)/ValObj)*100
        OptimalityGap=0
        Cuts=callback2.cuts+1
        Iter=callback2.iterationsR
        BestBound=callback2.mipnodeobjbnd
        LP_GORDO=callback2.TimeBetweenCalls
    #TIMELIMIT REACHED BUT INTEGER SOL EXISTS
    if solrEC_D.get_status()==107:
        ValObj=solrEC_D.get_objective_value()
        tiempos=elapsed
        nodos=-1
        MSJ=solrEC_D.status[solrEC_D.get_status()]
        COD=solrEC_D.get_status()
        ValRel=callback2.LPValueWithCuts
        tiemposRel=elapsedLP
        MIPGAP=-1                       
        OptimalityGap=callback1.MIP_relative_gap
        Cuts=callback2.cuts+1
        Iter=callback2.iterationsR
        BestBound=callback2.mipnodeobjbnd
        LP_GORDO=callback2.TimeBetweenCalls
     #TIMELIMIT REACHED BUT INTEGER SOL DOES NOT EXIST
    if solrEC_D.get_status()==108:
        ValObj=-1
        tiempos=elapsed
        nodos=-1
        MSJ=solrEC_D.status[solrEC_D.get_status()]
        COD=solrEC_D.get_status()
        ValRel=callback2.LPValueWithCuts
        tiemposRel=elapsedLP
        MIPGAP=-1                       
        OptimalityGap=-1
        Cuts=callback2.cuts+1
        Iter=callback2.iterationsR
        BestBound=callback2.mipnodeobjbnd
        LP_GORDO=callback2.TimeBetweenCalls                        
    #INFEASIBLE OR UNBOUNDED
    if solrEC_D.get_status()==119:
        ValObj=-1
        tiempos=elapsed
        nodos=-1
        MSJ=solrEC_D.status[solrEC_D.get_status()]
        COD=solrEC_D.get_status()
        ValRel=-1
        tiemposRel=-1
        MIPGAP=-1                       
        OptimalityGap=-1
        Cuts=-1
        Iter=-1 
        BestBound=-1
        LP_GORDO=0

    return ValObj,tiempos,nodos, MSJ,COD,ValRel,tiemposRel,MIPGAP,OptimalityGap,Cuts,Iter,BestBound,LP_GORDO
```

Now the other code files that are called for the first:

G_callbacks:

```py
from __future__ import division
import cplex.callbacks
from cplex.callbacks import MIPInfoCallback
import G_SeparationProblems
import numpy
import operator

#MIPInfoCallback
class Nodos(MIPInfoCallback):
    num_nodes=-1
    best_OBJ=-1
    MIP_relative_gap=-1
    times_called =0
    LPSol= -1
    FirstT = 1
    stopinc=0
    #These values are set in case the problem is solved at the first iteration of the root, because if that happens I guess
    #we never even get to call the callback. In any case, that never happens for my instances.
    def __call__(self):
        self.times_called += 1
        self.num_nodes=self.get_num_nodes()
        self.best_OBJ=self.get_best_objective_value()
        self.MIP_relative_gap=self.get_MIP_relative_gap()
        if self.times_called==1 and self.FirstT == 1:
            self.LPSol=self.get_best_objective_value()
            self.stopinc=self.get_time()
            self.FirstT = 0

#IncumbentCallback
class Incumbente(cplex.callbacks.IncumbentCallback):
    def __call__(self):
        print "El callback Incumbente dice: "
        print self.get_solution_source()




class Cplex_callback_D2BC_C_norm(cplex.callbacks.UserCutCallback):
    def __init__(self,env):
        cplex.callbacks.UserCutCallback.__init__(self,env)
        self.env=env
    LPValueWithCuts=-1
    cuts=-1 
    iterations=0
    lb=-cplex.infinity
    ub=cplex.infinity
    lbPrimal=-cplex.infinity
    iterationsR=0
    times_called=0
    BeenOptimal=0
    alpha = 0

    q_sep={}
    theta_sep={}

    q_in={}
    theta_in={}
    cbasis={}
    vbasis={}
    te,ue,ve={},{},{}
    tr,ur,vr={},{},{}
    startic={}
    RepDif= 0
    Dif=0
    DifAnterior=0
    HaHabidoCortes=0
    TimeBetweenCalls=-1
    UES={}
    max_index={}
    max_value={}
    q_puedeser={}
    theta_puedeser={}
    fobj_puedeser={}
    cambio={}
    def __call__(self):

        if self.model._Counter == 1:
            print "EN EL USER CUT CALLBACK : %s" %self.model._ValorObjetivoMejorado
            Vars=sorted(self.thetaVars.values())
            coeffs = {}
            for k in range(self.model._K):
                if not self.thetaVars[k] in coeffs:
                    coeffs[self.thetaVars[k]]=0
                coeffs[self.thetaVars[k]]+=self.model._p[k]
            self.add(cut=cplex.SparsePair(ind=coeffs.keys(),val=coeffs.values()),sense="L", rhs=self.model._ValorObjetivoMejorado,use=0)

        self.model._Counter = 0

        self.ub=self.get_objective_value()
        print "ITERACION %s" %(self.times_called)
        self.nodecnt=self.get_num_nodes()
        print "Callback called %s times" %self.times_called
        if self.times_called==0:
            for k in range(self.model._K):
                for j in range(self.model._J):
                    self.q_in[k,j]=self.model._qH[k,j]


            for k in range(self.model._K):
                self.theta_in[k]=self.model._thetaH[k]

        self.DifAnterior=self.ub-self.lb

        if self.RepDif >= 30:
            print "SALTANDO QUE ES GERUNDIO!"
            self.lb=self.ub

        self.times_called+=1

        self.startic[self.times_called] = self.model.get_time()
        if self.nodecnt == 0 and self.times_called>=2:
            self.TimeBetweenCalls=self.startic[self.times_called]-self.startic[self.times_called-1]

        r=1
        self.mipnodeobjbnd = self.get_objective_value()

        if self.nodecnt == 1 and self.model._FirstTime == 1:
            self.stopic = self.model.get_time()
            self.model._FirstTime=0
        if self.nodecnt >= 0:
            self.stopic = self.model.get_time()


            Vars2=sorted(self.thetaVars.values())
            theta=self.get_values(Vars2)
            Vars=sorted(self.qVars.values())
            a=self.get_values(Vars)
            data=numpy.array(a)
            shape=(self.model._K, self.model._J)
            q=data.reshape(shape)

            sub={}



            self.lbPrimal=self.get_incumbent_objective_value()

            tr,ur,vr={},{},{}
            self.CurrentBestObjBound=self.get_best_objective_value()
            self.CurrentBestObj=self.get_incumbent_objective_value()

            if self.ub-self.lbPrimal > 1e-4*self.ub:

                self.alpha = 1


                for k in range(self.model._K):
                    for j in range(self.model._J):
                        self.q_sep[k,j]=self.alpha*q[k,j]+(1-self.alpha)*self.q_in[k,j]
                for k in range(self.model._K):
                    self.theta_sep[k]=self.alpha*theta[k]+(1-self.alpha)*self.theta_in[k]
            print self.ub
            print self.lb
            if self.ub-self.lb > 1e-4*self.ub:
                self.HaHabidoCortes=0
                for k in range(self.model._K):
                    h=0

                    sub=G_SeparationProblems.SeparationProblem_q_C_norm(self.model._p,self.q_sep,self.theta_sep,self.model._I,self.model._J,self.model._K,self.model._R,self.model._C)
                    sub.set_problem_type(sub.problem_type.LP)
                    print "El Problema es un %s: %s" %(sub.get_problem_type(),sub.problem_type[sub.get_problem_type()])

                    sub.parameters.preprocessing.presolve.set(sub.parameters.preprocessing.presolve.values.off)
                    sub.parameters.lpmethod.set(sub.parameters.lpmethod.values.primal)
                    sub.solve()


                    if sub.solution.get_status()==sub.solution.status.optimal:
                        print "Estamos dentro para recuperar vertice" 
                        a,aa={},{}
                        verticealpha={}
                        a=sub.solution.get_values(range(0,self.model._K*self.model._I,1))
                        data=numpy.array(a)
                        shape=(self.model._K,self.model._I)
                        aa=data.reshape(shape)
                        for k in range(self.model._K):
                            for i in range(self.model._I):
                                verticealpha[k,g,i]=aa[k,i]

                        b,bb={},{}
                        verticebeta={}
                        b=sub.solution.get_values(range(self.model._K*self.model._I, self.model._K*self.model._I+self.model._K*self.model._J,1))
                        data=numpy.array(b)
                        shape=(self.model._K,self.model._J)
                        bb=data.reshape(shape)
                        for k in range(self.model._K):
                            for j in range(self.model._J):
                                verticebeta[k,g,j]=bb[k,j]

                        c,cc={},{}
                        verticegamma={}
                        c=sub.solution.get_values(range(self.model._K*self.model._I+self.model._K*self.model._J, self.model._K*self.model._I+self.model._K*self.model._J+self.model._K*self.model._J*self.model._J,1))
                        data=numpy.array(c)
                        shape=(self.model._K, self.model._J, self.model._J)
                        cc=data.reshape(shape)
                        for k in range (self.model._K):
                            for l in range (self.model._J):
                                for j in range (self.model._J):
                                    verticegamma[k,g,l,j]=cc[k,l,j]

                        ll={}
                        verticelamb={}
                        ll=sub.solution.get_values(range(self.model._K*self.model._I+self.model._K*self.model._J+self.model._K*self.model._J*self.model._J,self.model._K*self.model._I+self.model._K*self.model._J+self.model._K*self.model._J*self.model._J+self.model._K,1))
                        for k in range(self.model._K):
                            verticelamb[k,g]=ll[k]


                        h=h+1

                    self.iterations=self.iterations+1
                    print "h=%s" %h

                    if h!=0:
                        for a in range(h-1,h,1):
                            if(sum(self.theta_sep[k]*(1+self.model._p[k]*verticelamb[k,a]) for k in range(self.model._K))-1e-4> sum(self.q_sep[k,j]*verticebeta[k,a,j] for k in range(self.model._K) for j in range(self.model._J))):
                                self.HaHabidoCortes=1
                                r=r+1
                                coeffs={} 
                                for k in range(self.model._K): 
                                    if not self.thetaVars[k] in coeffs: 
                                        coeffs[self.thetaVars[k]]=0 
                                    coeffs[self.thetaVars[k]]+=(1+self.model._p[k]*verticelamb[k,a]) 
                                for k in range(self.model._K):
                                    for j in range(self.model._J):
                                        if not self.qVars[k,j] in coeffs:
                                            coeffs[self.qVars[k,j]]=0
                                        coeffs[self.qVars[k,j]]-=verticebeta[k,a,j] #0 mas eso
                                self.add(cut=cplex.SparsePair(ind=coeffs.keys(),val=coeffs.values()), sense="L", rhs=0, use=self.use_cut.force)
                                print "CORTE DE OPTIMALIDAD AÑADIDO"

                    self.iterationsR += 1
                    self.lb=sub.solution.get_objective_value()

                    print "HAHABIDOCORTES: %s" %self.HaHabidoCortes
                    if self.HaHabidoCortes==0:
                        for k in range(self.model._K):
                            for j in range(self.model._J):
                                self.q_in[k,j]=self.q_sep[k,j]
                        for k in range(self.model._K):
                            self.theta_in[k]=self.theta_sep[k]

                    self.Dif=self.ub-self.lb
                    if self.DifAnterior-self.Dif==0:
                        self.RepDif+=1
                    print "DifAnterior:= %s -- Dif:= %s" %(self.DifAnterior, self.Dif)
            else:
                self.lb = -cplex.infinity


            print "**************************"
            print "NODE: %s" %self.nodecnt
            print "UPPER BOUND: %s" %self.ub
            print "LOWER BOUND D: %s" %self.lb
            print "LOWER BOUND P: %s" %self.lbPrimal
            print "**************************"

            self.cuts=self.get_num_cuts(134) #134 is user cuts
            self.startic[self.times_called] = self.model.get_time()

            if self.nodecnt>=0:
                self.LPValueWithCuts=sum(self.model._p[k]*theta[k] for k in range(self.model._K))
                self.model._LPValueWithCuts=self.LPValueWithCuts
```

G_heuristica

```py
import operator
import RANDUtilidades
import random

def HeuristicaGeneral(p,I,K,J,R,C):
    x={}
    q={}
    UES={}
    max_index={}
    max_value={}
    d={}
    s={}
    fobj={}

    for i in range(I):
        x[i]=float(1)
    for i in range(I):
        x[i]=x[i]/I

    for k in range(K):
        for j in range(J):
            UES[k,j]=sum(C[k,i,j]*x[i] for i in range(I))

    for k in range(K):
        max_index[k], max_value[k] = max(enumerate(UES[k,j] for j in range(J)), key=operator.itemgetter(1))

    for k in range(K):
        for j in range(J):
            if j == max_index[k]:
                q[k,j]=1
            else:
                q[k,j]=0

    for k in range(K):
        d[k]=sum(R[k,i,max_index[k]]*x[i] for i in range(I))

    for k in range(K):
        s[k]=sum(C[k,i,max_index[k]]*x[i] for i in range(I))
    fobj=sum(p[k]*d[k] for k in range(K))

    return s,d,x,q,fobj
```

D2MIPG:

```py
import cplex

def solveMIPpG(I,J,K,p,R,C):
    model = cplex.Cplex()
    #Definition of the variables
    x, q, z = {},{},{}
    for i in range(I):
        x[i]=model.variables.add(obj=[0],lb=[0],ub=[1],types=["C"], names=["x[%s]" %i])[0]
    for k in range(K):
        for j in range(J):
            q[k,j]=model.variables.add(obj=[0],lb=[0], types=["B"], names=["q[%s,%s]" %(k,j)])[0]
    for k in range(K):
        for j in range(J):
            for i in range(I):
                z[k,i,j]=model.variables.add(obj=[p[k]*R[k,i,j]], lb=[0], types=["C"], names=["z[%s,%s,%s]" %(k,i,j)])[0]


    model.objective.set_sense(model.objective.sense.maximize)

    #Model constraints
    #Suma qjs igual a 1.
    for k in range(K):
        model.linear_constraints.add(lin_expr=[cplex.SparsePair(ind=[q[k,j] for j in range(J)],val=[1.0]*J)], senses=["E"], rhs=[1], names=['SumaProbs[%s]' %k])[0]
    for k in range(K):
        for j in range(J):
            coef=[]
            for i in range(I):
                coef.append(1)
            coef.append(-1)
            var=[]
            for i in range(I):
                var.append(z[k,i,j])
            var.append(q[k,j])
            model.linear_constraints.add(lin_expr=[cplex.SparsePair(ind=var, val=coef)], senses=["E"], rhs=[0], names=['sumazsq[%s,%s]'%(k,j)])[0]
    for k in range(K):
        for i in range(I):
            coef2=[]
            for j in range(J):
                coef2.append(1)
            coef2.append(-1)
            var2=[]
            for j in range(J):
                var2.append(z[k,i,j])
            var2.append(x[i])
            model.linear_constraints.add(lin_expr=[cplex.SparsePair(ind=var2, val=coef2)], senses=["E"], rhs=[0], names=['sumazsx[%s,%s]'%(k,i)])[0]
    for k in range(K):
        for j in range(J):
            for l in range(J):
                if j!=l:
                    coef3=[]
                    for i in range(I):
                        coef3.append(C[k,i,l]-C[k,i,j])
                    var3=[]
                    for i in range(I):
                        var3.append(z[k,i,j])
                    model.linear_constraints.add(lin_expr=[cplex.SparsePair(ind=var3, val=coef3)], senses=["L"], rhs=[0], names=['bestresp[%s,%s,%s]'%(k,l,j)])[0]

    model._data = x, q, z
    # model.write("MIPpGHAHA.lp")
    return model

#This is the weak formulation D2  #Generador inicial del modelo  
def solveD2(I,J,K,p,R,C): 
    model = cplex.Cplex()
    #Definition of the variables
    theta, s ,q, x = {},{},{},{}
    for i in range(I):
        x[i]=model.variables.add(obj=[0],lb=[0],ub=[1],types=["C"], names=["x[%s]" %i])[0]
    for k in range(K):
        for j in range(J):
            q[k,j]=model.variables.add(obj=[0],lb=[0], types=["B"], names=["q[%s,%s]" %(k,j)])[0]
    for k in range(K):
        s[k] = model.variables.add(obj=[0], types=["C"], names=["s[%s]" % k])[0]
    for k in range(K):
        theta[k] = model.variables.add(obj=[p[k]], types=["C"], names=["theta[%s]" % k])[0]

    model.objective.set_sense(model.objective.sense.maximize)

    M1, M2= {}, {}
    M1 = 2 * max(R.values()) + 1
    M2 = 2 * max(C.values()) + 1

    #Constraints of the model
    #Suma qjs igual a 1.
    for k in range(K):
        model.linear_constraints.add(lin_expr=[cplex.SparsePair(ind=[q[k,j] for j in range(J)],val=[1.0]*J)], senses=["E"], rhs=[1], names=['SumaProbs[%s]' %k])[0]
    model.linear_constraints.add(lin_expr=[cplex.SparsePair(ind=[x[i] for i in range(I)],val=[1.0]*I)], senses=["E"], rhs=[1], names=['Sumaxs'])[0]

    for k in range(K):
        for j in range(J):
            coef=[]
            coef.append(1)
            for i in range(I):
                coef.append(-R[k,i,j])
            coef.append(M1)
            vars=[]
            vars.append(theta[k])
            for i in range(I):
                vars.append(x[i])
            vars.append(q[k,j])

            model.linear_constraints.add(lin_expr=[cplex.SparsePair(ind=vars, val=coef)], senses=["L"], rhs=[M1], names=['Bound_d[%s,%s]' %(k,j)])[0]
    for k in range(K):
        for j in range(J):
            coef2=[]
            coef2.append(1)
            for i in range(I):
                coef2.append(-C[k,i,j])
            coef2.append(M2)
            vars2=[]
            vars2.append(s[k])
            for i in range(I):
                vars2.append(x[i])
            vars2.append(q[k,j])
            coef3=[]
            coef3.append(1)
            for i in range(I):
                coef3.append(-C[k,i,j])
            vars3=[]
            vars3.append(s[k])
            for i in range(I):
                vars3.append(x[i])
            model.linear_constraints.add(lin_expr=[cplex.SparsePair(ind=vars2,val=coef2)],senses=["L"], rhs=[M2], names=['bound_s1[%s,%s]' %(k,j)])[0]
            model.linear_constraints.add(lin_expr=[cplex.SparsePair(ind=vars3, val=coef3)], senses=["G"], rhs=[0], names=['bound_s2[%s,%s]' %(k,j)])[0]    

    model._data = x, q, s, theta
    # model.write("D2HAHA.lp")
    return model
```

G_SeparationProblems

```py
def SeparationProblem_q_C_norm(p,q,theta,I,J,K,R,C):
    model=cplex.Cplex()
    alpha,beta,gamma,lamb={},{},{},{}
    for k in range(K):
        for i in range(I):
            alpha[k,i]=model.variables.add(obj=[0], lb=[-cplex.infinity], ub=[cplex.infinity], types=["C"], names=["alpha[%s,%s]"%(k,i)])[0]
    for k in range(K):
        for j in range(J):
            beta[k,j]=model.variables.add(obj=[q[k,j]], lb=[-cplex.infinity], ub=[cplex.infinity], types=["C"], names=["beta[%s,%s]"%(k,j)])[0]
    for k in range(K):
        for l in range(J):
            for j in range(J):
                gamma[k,l,j]=model.variables.add(obj=[0], lb=[0], ub=[cplex.infinity], types=["C"], names=["gamma[%s,%s,%s]"%(k,l,j)])[0]
    for k in range(K):
        lamb[k]=model.variables.add(obj=[p[k]*theta[k]], lb=[0], ub=[cplex.infinity], types=["C"], names=["lambda[%s]"%(k)])[0]            

    model.objective.set_sense(model.objective.sense.minimize)
    #Restricciones
    for k in range(K):
        for i in range(I):
            for j in range(J):
                var=[]
                var.append(alpha[k,i])
                var.append(beta[k,j])
                var.apend(lamb[k])
                for l in range(J):
                    if l!=j:
                        var.append(gamma[k,l,j])
                coef=[]
                coef.append(1)
                coef.append(1)
                coef.append(p[k]*R[k,i,j])
                for l in range(J):
                    if l!=j:
                        coef.append(C[k,i,l]-C[k,i,j])
                model.linear_constraints.add(lin_expr=[cplex.SparsePair(ind=var,val=coef)], senses=["G"], rhs=[0], names=['1era[%s,%s,%s]'%(k,i,j)])[0]

    for i in range(I):
        var=[]
        for k in range(K):
            var.append(alpha[k,i])
        coef=[]
        for k in range(K):
            coef.append(-1)
        model.linear_constraints.add(lin_expr=[cplex.SparsePair(ind=var,val=coef)], senses=["G"], rhs=[0], names=['2a[%s]'%(i)])[0]

    var=[]
    for k in range(K):
        var.append(lamb[k])
    for j in range(J):
        for k in range(K):
            var.append(beta[k,j])
    coef=[]
    for k in range(K):
        coef.append(-1)
    for j in range(J):
        for k in range(K):
            coef.append(1)
    model.linear_constraints.add(lin_expr=[cplex.SparsePair(ind=var,val=coef)], senses=["E"], rhs=[-1], names=['norm'])[0]


    model._data = alpha,beta,gamma,lamb
    return model
```

My instances are ok and running with other algorithms without problems.

Comment: Hi and welcome in StackOverflow! Please share the piece of code that caused the exception, so we can take a look :) You can edit your answer with the edit button.

Comment: Please edit your question to containt the relevant code. Check [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @MarcoBuster I uploaded the code. The main code is the first, I commented where the spyder says the error is, and I uploaded the other associated code files. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to debug errors in callbacks is to wrap your callback code into a `try/except` block, print the actual exception from that and then re-raise it:

```
try:
  # callback code here
  ...
except:
  print(sys.exc_info()[0])
  raise
```

That will tell you what exactly went wrong.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

I did it a few minutes ago, but I just got the message: Reloaded modules: G_SeparationProblems.

If i disable the UMR in python interpreter, to don't get that message, I don't get any output.

Comment: I am not sure what this message means. It sounds like an information message from spyder that the modified source file was loaded. Unfortunately, the code you posted is not self-contained, i.e., it does not contain everything that is required to reproduce your problem. So we can only make ild guesses of what may go wrong. One option would be to post everything, including input files. Another options would be to just add `print()` statements to the callback functions to trace how far you actually get. Do you have *any* successful callback invocation?

Comment: Hello. Apparently, the problem is in the separation problem that I'm using, cause I tried with another and it ran without any issue, it means that the callback is ok except for the separation problem used in it.

So, I'm trying now to debug the problem, but it seems to be ok. That separation problem in my question (the one I'm trying to debug).

Comment: Daniel. I really appreciate your time for helping me and suggesting me how to debug this. I finally found the error. It was a missing p in the 'append' in a variable in the separation problem. I think is a stupid error, but I'm pretty new in this and is not easy to see things. Thank you very much, this changed my life.

Comment: You are most welcome. Could you please also mark the question as answered? Either by accepting my answer or by providing a new answer in which you explain what finally helped you to track down the problem.